# C++ pass by reference: how is the call stack used?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, stack, pass-by-reference

A curiosity that's been nagging at me:

Consider this function:

```
void add10(int& x) {
    x += 10;
}
```

I've been programming in C for a long time, so I know exactly what it means to do this:

```
void add10(int *x) {
    (*x)+=10;
}
```

The address of x is pushed on the stack (along with the return address, dynamic link, etc.), and the function itself dereferences it.

But how is the call stack used in the first case? Is it simply a syntactic shortcut for the second case?

Comment: Same thing: a reference is usually implemented internally as a pointer. It's mostly a syntactic sugar.

Comment: _"Is it simply a syntactic shortcut for the second case?"_ That's implementation defined and not covered by the c++ standard.

Comment: [What was that](https://godbolt.org/g/mLS5cZ) about pushing the address onto the stack and everything?

Comment: Okay, okay, I lied; oftentimes values are passed to a function using registers... but imagine I passed 143 pointers to int to my function; I believe the question is still valid

Comment: It is not quite the same. You cannot have a null reference

Comment: It's up to the compiler how it does these things.    However, practically, the compiler may well convert the first case into something that uses a pointer behind the scenes - so the end result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic answer, as it depends on the compiler - it can do whatever it wants, as long as the result is correct.
Typically, it would be treated the same way as a pointer. Also, typically, it would be inlined, so nothing ever goes on the stack (but again, it depends on the compiler and the context)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it simply a syntactic shortcut for the second case?

That is implementation defined.

Usually yes, since the reference is internally implemented as a pointer.

---

PS: Your claims about how 2nd case works, are far from accurate. You need to re-approach it.